# Create new columns parsing SAS

Tags: sas

I have a column with different adresses, presented like this :

```
Mathilde 45 rue du Chemin neuf 35950 Chichigneux
```

I need to create  new columns, one for name (Mathilde here), one for the number (45), one for the street (rue du Chemin neuf), one for postal code (35950) and one for the city (Chichigneux).
I've managed to do everything but the street name with this code:

```
DATA DmExo3.Test;
    SET DmExo3.Adresses;
    /* Extraction du nom */
    Nom = scan(Contact, 1, ' ');
    /* Extraction du numéro de rue */
    Numero = scan(Contact, 2, ' '); 
    /* Extraction du nom de la rue */
    /* Extraction du code postal */
    CodePostal = input(scan(Contact, -2, ' '), 5.); 
    /* Extraction de la ville */
    Ville = scan(Contact, -1, ' ');
RUN;
```

I'm in a beginners class, so the answer shouldn't be too complicated, but I'm stuck since scan doesn't let you select several words. I've tried with substr, but the spot where the street name starts and ends changes with every address.

Answer (score 1):

Street is between numero and postal.

You can use the `findw()` function to locate the positions of the strings you found based on the earlier suppositions: (2nd word is numero, -2nd word is postal), and extract therein.

Is there a reason the postal code is being kept as a numeric variable?

```
data have;
  contact = 'Mathilde 45 rue du Chemin neuf 35950 Chichigneux';
run;

data want;
  set have;

  Nom    = scan(Contact,  1, ' ');
  Numero = scan(Contact,  2, ' '); 
  Postal = scan(Contact, -2, ' ');
  Ville  = scan(Contact, -1, ' ');

  p1 = findw(contact, trim(numero), ' ');
  p2 = findw(contact, trim(postal), ' ', 'b');

  if 0 < p1 < p2 then 
    street = substr(contact,p1,p2-p1);

  drop p1 p2;
run;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! Using your code, my street column still has the number in front of it. Any idea why?

Comment: Come on mate, figger it out.  p1 is the start place of numero, so add the length of numero to p1 before the if statement.